# Pythonic way to aggregate object properties in memory efficient way?

Tags: python, list, aggregate

For example we have large list of objects like this:

```
class KeyStatisticEntry:
    def __init__(self, value=""):
        self.usedBytes = len(value)
        self.encoding = get_string_encoding(value)

    @property
    def total(self):
        overhead = get_object_overhead(self.usedBytes)
        if self.encoding == 'some value':
            return overhead
        else:
            return self.usedBytes + overhead
    @property
    def aligned(self):
        return some_func_with(self.usedBytes)

    # Here is lots of calculated properties on basis of existing properties
```

And we need to agregate lots of metrix about this obejct - min, max, sum, mean, stdev values of it propertirs. Currently i do it with code like this:

```
used_bytes = [] 
total_bytes = []
aligned_bytes = []
encodings = []

for obj in keys.items():
    used_bytes.append(obj.usedBytes)
    total_bytes.append(obj.total)
    aligned_bytes.append(obj.aligned)
    encodings.append(obj.encoding)

total_elements = len(used_bytes)
used_user = sum(used_bytes)
used_real = sum(total_bytes)
aligned = sum(aligned_bytes)
mean = statistics.mean(used_bytes)
```

### Question:

Is here is more "pythonic" way with better perfomance and memory usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `operator.attrgetter` in order to get multiple attribute of your objects then use `itertools.zip_longest` (`itertools.izip_longest` in Python 2.X ) to attach the relative attributes together.

```
from operator import attrgetter
all_result = [attrgetter('usedBytes','total','aligned','encoding')(obj) for obj in keys.items()]
```

Or use a generator expression to create a generator instead of a list :

```
all_result = (attrgetter('usedBytes','total','aligned','encoding')(obj) for obj in keys.items())
```

Then use `zip_longest`:

```
used_bytes, total_bytes, aligned_bytes, encodings = zip_longest(*all_results)
```

Then use `map` function to apply the `sum` function on iterables for which you need the sum:

```
used_user, used_real, aligned = map(sum,(used_bytes, total_bytes, aligned_bytes))
```

And separately for `len` and `mean`:

```
total_elements = len(used_bytes)
mean = statistics.mean(used_bytes)
```

And if you want to handle all the sub lists as generator (which is more optimized in terms of memory use and less performance in terms of runtime) you can use a new class in order to calculate the desire result separately using generators :

```
from itertools import tee
class Aggregator:
    def __init__(self, all_obj):
        self.obj = all_obj
        self.used_user, self.mean = self.getTotalBytesAndMean()
        self.total_elements = len(self.all_obj)
        self.aligned = self.getAligned()

    def getTotalBytesAndMean(self):
        iter_1, iter_2 = tee((obj.usedBytes for obj in self.all_obj))
        return sum(iter_1), statistics.mean(iter_2)

    def getTotal(self):
        return sum(obj.total for obj in self.all_obj)

    def getAligned(self):
        return sum(obj.aligned for obj in self.all_obj)

    def getEncoding(self):
        return (obj.encoding for obj in self.all_obj)
```

Then you can do :

```
Agg = Aggregator(keys.items())

# And simply access to attributes
Agg.used_user
```

Comment: is all_result is actualy list of generators?

Comment: @misterion The first one wasn't  list of generators, because `attrgetter` doesn't returns a generator. If you want a generator you can use a generator expression instead of list comprehension. Chek the edit.

Comment: tnx @Kasramvd, i'm new to python - can you also help with this: here is no way to aggregate all data without materializeing data with zip_longest. I mean if i have list of 32 millions of object i would have N lists of 32 millions of properties? here is no any way to make computation with generator?

Comment: @misterion In that case I think you need to use another object for aggregating all of them in generator mode. Let me update the answer. –

Comment: Awesome! Tnx @Kasramvd!

Answer (score 0):

There is a probably better way for memory usage, using (implicit) generators instead of lists for getting all your infos. I am not sure it will be better if you are doing many computations on the same list (for example for usedBytes). Note however that you cannot use `len` on a generator (but the length would be the length of your input list anyway):

```
total_elements = len(keys.items())
used_user = sum(obj.usedBytes for obj in keys.items())
used_real = sum(obj.total for obj in keys.items())
aligned = sum(obj.aligned for obj in keys.items())
mean = statistics.mean(obj.usedBytes for obj in keys.items())
```